# Issue in saving "Specialities" multi select drop down in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

I had created the new field "Specialities" multiselect drop down.When I select the values they are getting selected but when we save them they are not saving .

Can anybody please help me what's wrong.

```
class Labwise_Hospital_Block_Adminhtml_Hospital_Edit_Tab_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form{

 protected function _prepareForm()
{
       $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
        $this->setForm($form);
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset("hospital_form", array("legend"=>Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Item information")));

        $fieldset->addField("name", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Hospital Name"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "name",
        ));

        $fieldset->addField("hospital_image", "image", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Hospital Image"),
        "name" => "hospital_image",
        ));         

        $fieldset->addField("username", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("UserName"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "username",
        ));

        $fieldset->addField("password", "password", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Password"),
        "class"     => "required-entry",
        "required"  => true,
        "name"      => "password",                  
        ));


        $fieldset->addField("email", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Email"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "email",
        )); 


        $fieldset->addField("address1", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Address1"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "address1",
        ));
        $fieldset->addField("address2", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Address2"),                            
        "name" => "address2",
        ));
        $fieldset->addField("city", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("City"),
        "class" => "required-entry",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "city",
        ));
        $fieldset->addField("location", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Location"),
        "name" => "location",
        ));     

        $fieldset->addField("mobilenumber", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Mobile Number"),
        "class" => "validate-digits validate-number8",
        "name" => "mobilenumber",
        ));

        $fieldset->addField("pincode", "text", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Zip Code"),
        "class" => "required-entry validate-zip-international",
        "required" => true,
        "name" => "pincode",
        ));

        $fieldset->addField("specialties", "multiselect", array(
        "label"     => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Specialties"),
        "name"      => "Specialties[]",
        "note"      => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("Specialties"),

        "values"    => array(
                  '-1'=> array( 'label' => 'Please Select....', 'value' => '-1'),
                  '1' => array(
                           'value'=> array(array('value'=>'2' , 'label' => 'Radiology') , array('value'=>'3' , 'label' =>'Pathology'), array('value'=>'4' , 'label' => 'MRI/Scan/X-Ray') , array('value'=>'5' , 'label' =>'Cardiac'), array('value'=>'6' , 'label' => 'Skin Care') , array('value'=>'7' , 'label' =>'Hair Care') , array('value'=>'8' , 'label' => 'Neurology ') , array('value'=>'9' , 'label' =>'Psychiatry') , array('value'=>'9' , 'label' => 'Nutrition & Dietetics ') , array('value'=>'10' , 'label' =>'Obstetrics & Gynaecology')),

                         ),                               

             ),

        ));

        $fieldset->addField("isregister", "checkbox", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("isRegister"),
        "name" => "isregister",
        "onclick"    => "this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;"
        ));

        $fieldset->addField("isnabl", "checkbox", array(
        "label" => Mage::helper("hospital")->__("isNABL"),
        "name" => "isnabl",
        "onclick"    => "this.value = this.checked ? 1 : 0;"
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->gethospitalData())
        {
            $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->gethospitalData());
            Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->sethospitalData(null);
        } 
        elseif(Mage::registry("hospital_data")) {
            $form->setValues(Mage::registry("hospital_data")->getData());
            $form->getElement("isregister")->setIsChecked(Mage::registry("hospital_data")->getIsregister());
        }
        return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

Comment: please show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add two function on form class which  will done option mapping

### Create a helper class where you can map at option

```
<?php
class Labwise_Hospital_Helper_Options {
        static public function getOptionArray0()
        {
            $data_array=array(); 
            $data_array[0]='Radiology';
            $data_array[1]='Pathology';
            $data_array[2]='MRI/Scan/X-Ray';
            return($data_array);
        }
        static public function getValueArray0()
        {
            $data_array=array();
            foreach($this->getOptionArray0() as $k=>$v){
               $data_array[]=array('value'=>$k,'label'=>$v);        
            }
            return($data_array);

        }

}
?>
```

### Then call the options at form

```
$fieldset->addField('specialties', 'multiselect', array(
    'label'     => Mage::helper('hospital')->__('Specialties'),
    'values'   => Mage::helper('hospital/options')->getValueArray0(),
    'name' => 'specialties',
));


Just add code before     $post_data['isregister'] = $post_data['isregister']==1?1:0;
```

**Addded code:**

if (isset($post_data['specilaities'])&& is_array($post_data['specilaities'])){

```
        $data['specilaities'] = implode(',',$this->getRequest()->getParam('specilaities'));
```

}
See

Comment: We need to add the code in same file or different files please mention

Comment: on same file.But it will be good idea .Put the two static function on model/helper class then call it option from there.

Comment: I had copied the code in the same file but it is showing an empty page can u please suggest

Comment: There was a mistake helper class Mage::helper('modulename') should be  Mage::helper('hospital')

Comment: Helloo can u please help me i had added the new column in DB also but iti is not saving please suggest me

Comment: have you check the what value passing on save action controller?

Comment: I had attached the save action() please check it

Comment: I added the code but it is not getting saved

Comment: how can i store it in DB please suggest me i could not save the values to DB.